# Robust path to visual studio's vcvars64.bat

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

VisualStudio has vcvars64.bat that loads all necessary environment variables to compile visual studio projects from the command line.

In VisualStudio 2017 community edition, this file for example resides in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
```

How can I construct the path to this file in a batch script, only using system set environment variables, independently of which visual studio version is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vswhere` to detect the install location of Visual Studio related files. This snippet from the [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Start-Developer-Command-Prompt) comes pretty close to what you need:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`vswhere.exe -prerelease -latest -property installationPath`) do (
  if exist "%%i\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat" (
    %comspec% /k "%%i\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat" %*
    exit /b
  )
)

rem Instance or command prompt not found
exit /b 2
```

Changing that snippet to call vcvars should be easy.

If you have multiple Visual Studio installations that may not have the C++ workload installed, you can search for an instance with a specific workload or component, like this one looking for Team Explorer to be part of the installation:

```
vswhere -latest -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamExplorer -property installationPath
```

The Microsoft C++ team wrote [a blog about vswhere and alternative options](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/finding-the-visual-c-compiler-tools-in-visual-studio-2017/). They also list all of the relevant workload and component identifiers.

The idea is that you ship `vswhere.exe` with your scripts or executable. Or downlead it on demand. I use this powershell snippet in a few places to grab vswhere when I need it:

```bsh
$vswhereLatest = "https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/releases/latest/download/vswhere.exe"
$vswherePath = ".\vswhere.exe"
remove-item $vswherePath
invoke-webrequest $vswhereLatest -OutFile $vswherePath
```

The reason behind this, is that you can now install multiple instances of the same Visual Studio Version. Each stores its settings in a private registry file. There is no easy way to get to the `InstallPath` registry key that used to exist. [More background can be found here](https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2017/06/29/changing-visual-studio-2017-private-registry-settings/). Complete with a few `reg.exe` commands to load the private registry hyves and query them. It you really can't package or fetch `vswhere` on demand, this may be your only option (add `16.*`to include 2019)

```
for /d %%f in (%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_*) do reg load HKLM\_TMPVS_%%~nxf "%%f\privateregistry.bin"

REM Use `reg query` to grab the InstallPath from the instance

for /d %%f in (%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_*) do reg unload HKLM\_TMPVS_%%~nxf
```

> Note: Looks like this may need to be updated to search for `15.*_*` and `16.*_*` to detect point releases as well as Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: vswhere doesn't seem to be in the PATH by default?

Comment: No, you need to pack it with your scripts or grab it on demand. Same applies to the powershell module.